# Opencart Set default tax class to all items

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart, opencart

I am working on a Opencart project and it is for Australia customers. So I have to set GST 10% to all items. The items are already added to the cart and I figured a way to add tax classes and I added it to a product and it works good.

The problem is the catalog has more than 10000 products already and I need to update tax classes to all the products. I knew we can run a query to do that but my question is "Is there a way to set a tax class to default" Please let me know. Thanks

My Opencart version is 1.5.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use SQL. You will need to run the following code in your phpMyAdmin or whatever other tool you use for SQL on your server

```
UPDATE `product` SET `tax_class_id` = '123';
```

changing `123` to the tax class ID. You may also need to add a database prefix to the table name `product` depending on your setup

## EDIT

To get this to work with new products by default, open `/admin/controller/catalog/product.php` and change this line

```
$this->data['tax_class_id'] = 0;
```

setting the `0` to the tax class ID

Comment: Thanks for giving me the exact query. Still my question is unanswered as I need to know how to make it default for the future products without touching the core code. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my setup (1.5.3.1) and it seemed to work ok; Assuming that all those products you have entered are set to the same existing Tax Class? If that's the case, then you can edit that Tax Class that the majority of products are on, and then change the **Tax Rate** for that class to a GST Tax Rate you create. You should also be able to rename that Tax Class so it appears as GST on the actual website. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but the problem is none of the products are assigned to any of the tax classes. So I couldn't apply your solution.

Comment: I see... How did you get those products into OpenCart in the first place? Did you use an import module?

Comment: Good question. Actually I am not aware about GST for Australia and the Client already added products before that integration. My mistake :)